# Using iCheck: checkbox and label on different lines (want them inline)

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4, icheck

I am using the jquery plugin iCheck to style my checkboxes.  I have successfully done this, but now I am not able to get the checkbox and label on the same line.

Here is the main code:

```
<ul class="facebook-friends">

        @foreach ($friends as $friend)

        <li>
        <div class="facebook_friend">
        <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
        <label for="{{$friend}}" style="display:block;">
        <span class="icon"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40"></a></span>
        </label>
        </div>
        </li>

        @endforeach                     
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook_friend {
    width:150px;
}

.icon {
    width:45px;
}

ul.facebook-friends {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    *zoom:1;
    width:500px;
    font-family:'proxima-nova';
    font-size:12px;


    color:#999

}

ul.facebook-friends li {

    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:0;
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0px;

    margin: 5px;

}
```

The iCheck box renders like so:

```
<div class="icheckbox_square-blue" style="position: relative;">
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend" id="3607" value="3607" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
</div>
```

The image that I am using for the label for the checkbox appears on the line under the check boxes.  Do you see anything that would make this be the case?  I would like them in line.  I am using Laravel 4.

Comment: i still wonder where this has anything todo with laravel. nobody cares WHERE you generate the HTML code, when you have problems with the styling of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move you `input/checkbox` inside the label, like

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($friends as $friend)
        <li>
            <div class="facebook_friend">
                <label for="{{$friend}}" style="display:block;">
                    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}">
                                <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40">
                            </a>
                        </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

[**DEMO HERE**.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6AeH5/3/)

Comment: Did not work.  I believe the "div" that is formed from iCheck is forcing the label to the next line.  Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: You can see how iCheck renders the input in my question.

Comment: The `ins` is positioned `absolute` and if you can change this then you can get the desire result, is that possible or plugin generates it ?

Comment: The plugin generates it

Comment: Can you change `.icheckbox {
    width: 20px;
}` ?

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/b2UwH/2/), just changed `.icheckbox { width: 20px; }` from `100%`.

Comment: In their first example (http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/), they have the label and text box in line...I'm not sure how they did this.

Comment: It's most probably they have used their `css` which is being used for the plugin.

Comment: From where did you get `.icheckbox {
    width: 100%;
}` ?

Comment: And I had it at a width and height of 22px anyways.

Comment: When I inspect the element...it shows the line after the checkbox is a margin

Comment: Add `!important` like `.icheckbox { width: 22px !important; }` and see.

Comment: As an alternative you may try `$('icheckbox').css({'width':'22px !important'})` after you initialize the plugin.

Comment: I think it's because iCheck is generating a div, as you can see in my question.  So it will move the label to the next line.

Comment: If this is a div then set it's display property to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: it generates the div on load unfortunately...I have it set up as an input box.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake that you might have missed,

I have creates a sample [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/6AeH5/1/) to explain the proof,

Just modify your code like this ..

```
  <ul>
  @foreach ($friends as $friend)
    <li>
    <div class="facebook_friend">
    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
    <label for="{{$friend}}"> /* Removed display:block here */
    <span class="icon"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40"></a></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
```

I have removed `style="display:block"` from `label` tag, that did trick,

Check the fiddle for small sample,

Edit: As these one is not working changing the style sheet that might be adding more style,

```
ul.facebook-friends li {
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:0px; /* this was lfet you need to correct it*/
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left:0; /* this was over ridden by the 5px as it was specified after */
    position:relative;
}
```

Edit 2 :Updated Fiddle

I have updated fiddle to verify your code [`fiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/6AeH5/4/) but here also this works fine..!!

Please provide live link of your page for further help, thank you

Comment: Did not work.  I believe the "div" that is formed from iCheck is forcing the label to the next line.  Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: I think that was the only problem, try remove float left from the li style please see updated answer, in my fiddle it is working so here also it should work, or else please post link for live page for better idea. thank you

Comment: Please check updated fiddle2 that is working fine with your provided CSS

Comment: Fiddle is not working, the host including icheck.min.js does not host this file any more

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue where I also want the checkbox aligned inline, but I needed the text on the right to be able to span on 2 lines without going below the checkbox

[Check fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ozeone/nbx61ujw/)

Seems the trick with aligning the checkbox is to have another container around it (in my case `<i>`) that i positioned absolute, changing the default checkbox container position will mess up the clickable area.

```
<div class="rcb-recent">
<div class="rcb-recent-items">
    <!-- ROW -->
    <div class="rcb-recent-item">
        <i>
            <input type="checkbox" class="recent-cb" checked="checked" />
        </i>
        <span>
            <a href="#">1-year Master in International Cooperation &amp; Development</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- ROW -->
    <div class="rcb-recent-item">
        <i>
            <input type="checkbox" class="recent-cb" checked="checked" />
        </i>
        <span>
            <a href="#">1-year Master in International Cooperation &amp; Development</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.rcb-recent {
  width: 200px
}

.rcb-recent-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.rcb-recent-item i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.rcb-recent-item span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```